# Boost Beast reconnect websocket connection after close

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, boost-beast

I am using boost::beast to create a websocket connection and so far it seems to work fine. But I am unable to figure out if i should replace the websocket::stream variable after disconnect.

i.e. I have a variable:

```
boost::beast::websocket::stream<boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>> _ws
```

After an async disconnect is initiated and completed:

```
bool WebsocketConnection::startDisconnectSequence()
{
    _ws.async_close(
        boost::beast::websocket::close_code::normal,
        boost::asio::bind_executor(
            _strand,
            std::bind(
                &WebsocketConnection::onClose,
                this,
                std::placeholders::_1)));

    return true;
}
```

If I want to restart again, should i replace the _ws variable

```
    boost::asio::async_connect(
        _ws.next_layer().next_layer(),
        results.begin(),
        results.end(),
        boost::asio::bind_executor(
            _strand,
            std::bind(
                &ASIOConnectionBase::onConnect,
                this,
                std::placeholders::_1)));
}
```

Comment: What are your findings?